# Magento 1 configuration in .htaccess is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, session, php-7, cookie

In magento

i have added the below configuration in **.htaccess** file

```
php_value session.cookie_secure 1
php_value session.cookie_httponly 1

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value session.cookie_httponly 1
  php_value session.cookie_secure 1
</IfModule>
```

**But still in cookies there is no** `secure` or `http_only` **flag set in it.**

Any thoughts or suggestions ?